# Android Device Monitor does not list Application for events?

Tags: logging, resource-monitoring

I'm worried about some activities showing up in logcat, but the "Application" field is empty on every entry.  Is there some way to get this populated?

WalletGuns and GnsSdk are related, but I can't identify what app is throwing the errors.

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful: [How to find the PID of an app (without ADB)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228386/44325)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not very explicit, but for production ROMs, applications will need to have set the `debuggable` attribute in their [Android Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) to `true`.

```
<application android:debuggable="true"
   ... />
```

Otherwise, no Application tag will appear.

So, probably, the developers for the apps in question have either ignored the attribute (default is false), or specified the attribute as false explicitly.

Comment: Good to know, but literally no events (tens of thousands) have this field populated.  I think I'm missing something else.

Comment: Generally, debug builds (apps) will spit out far more logcat information.  Release builds are stripped of their logs automatically.  Wish I had a better solution for you.