# On a non-rooted device, can adb access any files that an Android file manager cannot?

Tags: adb, data-recovery, file-system, cache, temp-files

An Android app I was relying on did not save its data.  I'm hoping that perhaps the data is located in a cache or temporary file.

The device is not rooted (and is running Android 7.0), and I've scoured all storage accessible without root using a couple different file managers.  Neither found anything of interest.

Using `adb`, is it possible to see more data on a non-rooted device than a file manager can inspect?

If not, is there another technique to accomplish this?

---

***Update:***

More specific details were requested, so they are presented here:

I was using the [Mega Call Recorder Advanced](https://web.archive.org/web/20200430183310/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callrecorder.procallrecorder) Android app to record phone calls.  At the end of a critical call, I went to copy the recording to a backup device.  The call was not present in the list of recordings.  Of course, that doesn't mean the call wasn't recorded by the app; it just means the final recording did not make it into its output folder (which does happen sometimes with that app). It is possible that the recording is stored in a cache or temporary file somewhere on the device.

Comment: The answer is yes... But if your comparing it to root it's likely not what your looking for. If you would be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish, we may be able to assist you.

Comment: As I see it, the only hope you have is to use `adb backup` for that app. This can work only if your app allows its data to be backed up. Otherwise, you are done for.

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you for your request for more details.  I have added them to the question.

Comment: Have you tried something like Solid Explorer and enable it's root file system? It doesn't require root to read most things, although you will get a few security prompts. I am not familiar with this app but in general apps only get access, even temporarily, to their own directories, so look in areas like the Android/data/{app} folder. Apps don't usually get access to "temp" or cache storage directly, but it maybe a partial file in it's own folders.

Comment: @acejavelin I took a look using Solid Explorer (SE).  There is no `Android` folder reported in the root, but there is a `data` folder.  When I click on the `data` folder, SE reports *Unable to browse the directory under "/data".*.  Did I follow your instructions correctly?

Comment: if app is debuggable you can access /data/data/pkgname from adb run-as

Comment: @alecxs Thanks.  When `adb` was first released, I used it quite a bit, but I haven't used it very much in recent years.  How do you determine if app is debuggable, and if it is, what `adb` command would be used to access `/data/data`?

Comment: @alecxs What's your fax number? I'll fax you a cup of coffee.  ;)

Comment: @alecxs Done. Now I have two cups. ;)

Comment: @Firelord In reading the official ADB documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb), I'm not seeing `adb backup`.  Do you have a good official reference for that command?  I found https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices, but that's unofficial and the info is almost a decade old.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket that linked question has relevant answers, despite their age.

Comment: is your device mediatek chipset? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219346

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/48609
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182403

Comment: @alecxs No problem.  I just took a look and left a comment.  I also upvoted your question so Roomba doesn't eventually delete it. :)