# When performing an adb pull of an entire device, why do I see /proc/self/root in pathnames repetitively?

Tags: adb, file-system, file-transfer, file-management, export

When performing `adb pull /` on a non-rooted device, I see hundreds of items with pathnames that begin with `/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root/proc/self/root`?

That's not a typo.  That is literally how the path of each of these items is prefaced.

It looks recursive or like an infinite loop, but eventually the repetition ends with a unique file or folder name.

What is going on?  What is `adb` doing here?

Comment: Usually that happens when dealing with `chroot` and/or mount namespace. `/proc/<pid>/root` points to the `rootfs` a process is seeing. Doing `adb pull` on "entire device" doesn't make sense. You should at maximum pull only persistent storage partitions, not pseudo filesystems.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes, I'm undoubtedly trying to capture a gnat with too large of a net.  I was trying to apply some of the tips provided in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234446/on-a-non-rooted-device-can-adb-access-any-files-that-an-android-file-manager-ca, and so I cast the net as wide and large as possible.  I'm searching for anywhere the lost data could be stored (cache, temp files, etc.), and so I tried pulling everything starting at root to try to get everything possible.

Comment: User data is stored nowhere ever except on `/data`.

Comment: `/` is just tmpfs in RAM and does not survive reboot. there is no benefit in pulling `/` no matter device is rooted or unrooted. it makes lot more sense to pull physical partitions, although only one partition is of any use

Comment: And also that won't succeed because some pseudo files (like `/dev/zero` and `/dev/urandom`) have no end of file. You'll get an infinitely increasing file.